# Instance variable not set in one function of class

Tags: php, moodle

this problem is really hurting my head.

I am working on a custom grade export plugin for Moodle, and have sub-classed the grade_export class:

```
class grade_export_sitscsv extends grade_export {
...
```

The form I have created sets two custom variables, so I have implemented a *process_form()* function, which then calls the function in the parent class:

```
function process_form($formdata) {
  $this->grade_item = preg_replace('/itemids\[([0-9]+)\]/','\1',$formdata->grade_item);
  $this->sits_assnum = $formdata->sits_assnum;

  parent::process_form($formdata);
}
```

I can see that these instance variables are set in my *display_preview()* function:

```
public function display_preview() {
  echo("<h2>Do we need a preview?</h2>");
  echo("<p> Grade item: ".$this->grade_item.", SITS num: ".$this->sits_assnum."</p>");
}
```

(Prints, for example, **Grade item: 7487, SITS num: 7**).

However, when I try to use the variables in the *print_grades()* function, they are not set:

```
public function print_grades() {
    global $CFG;
    echo("Grade item: ".$this->grade_item.", SITS num: ".$this->sits_assnum."\n");
```

... prints **Grade item: , SITS num:** to my output file.

I would appreciate any suggestions that could help me resolve this.

Comment: Please post the code where you are calling `print_grades()`.

Comment: Is `print_grades()` being called after `process_form()`?

Comment: Thanks, all. I worked out the answer with the help of a colleague...

I was (foolishly) expecting the same object to be in scope all the way through. Instead, the data was being written into a form in an intermediate page, and then a new instance of the object was being created after that form was submitted. I had to override the get_export_params() method, of grade_export (to add my paramaters), and then add them in my export.php file and make sure they were passed to the constructor.

D'Oh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, Michael and mkaatman - I did work it out finally, with the help of a colleague.

The problem was, the object that **print_grades()** was being called on, was not the same object as when **display_preview()** was being called, even though it was the same class - the values from **process_form()** were written into another form (as *<input type="hidden"...* elements) in an intermediate page, and a new object was instantiated from this data.

I just needed to ensure that my data was being written into the second form, and then passed to the new object.